# RHO mobiles +Ruby for mac OS X 10.6.4

Tags: macos, rhodes

i want to work in RHO mobiles i had done some r&d and cam to know that ruby is needed for that.
I want to install ruby and RHOMobile in mac OS X 10.6.4 to work in rhomobiles.
I had got some idea through this link:-

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/install

Please anyone help me and guide me for this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** - You need download an tools http://rhomobile.com/rhostudio-mac

**2** - You need run both script ("Install gems" and "Install gems on rvm").

**3** - Enter version (for exemple 1.8.7 or 1.9.2) and your mac account password (for exemple - 12345)

**4** - Wait until it install (3 - 7 minutes)

**5** - Drag RhoStudio to the applications folder.